# Can not PING to another computer in another local network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have 2 routers in my house. The first one connects to the internet, and the other connects to the first router via switch. I attached the illustration in this post.

[image: my network map]

The thing is, my PC can not PING to the second router (192.168.1.1), and also the computer connected to it (192.168.1.100)
My second computer can not PING  my PC (192.168.0.25), but it can PING  the first router (192.168.0.1). The second computer can connect to the internet normally.

Is my network mapping right or are there other things that make the problem occurs like firewall, etc.?

Comment: This is a small network (like mine and others). Put the second router on the same subnet as the first. Then everything will connect.

Comment: Is your mask blocking it with 255.255.255.0 ?

Comment: If your second router (Router1) is performing NAT for PC1 then the rest of your network is as if it were the internet to PC1. This is why PC0 cannot directly access PC1. You will need to turn off DHCP on Router1 and plug Switch0 into one of Router1's LAN ports. You should also change Router1's IP address to be on the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet. Make sure Router0's DHCP range will not conflict with the address you assign to Router1.

Answer (score -1):

Gather information.
Isolate the problem.
Analyze the problem.
Test a fix.
Repeat.

This is Troubleshooting 101. First, gather information. For each computer:

IP Address:
Subnet Mask:
Default Gateway:
Software Firewall Enabled?
Antivirus or Security Software installed?

Are they using the same gateway and subnet? If not, they probably won’t talk. Is there a software firewall like Windows Firewall enabled? If so, you’ll need to add an exception for Synergy (recommended) or turn off the firewall (not recommended). Ping can also be disabled on a machine, so that’s possible too.

Most likely? They’re not on the same network - 192.168.1.x is not the same network as 192.168.0.x when using a /24 CIDR (a subnet that is 255.255.255.0).

Answer (score -2):

use a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0 on the adapters and routers when accessing two different 192.168.x.x networks.